# ¿Existe la expresión "tocar a su inicio"?

Tags: significado

"Tocar a su fin" significa llegar al final ([definición](https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=tocar%20a%20su%20fin), [ejemplos](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/spanish-english/tocar-a-su-fin)). ¿Entonces se puede inducir que "tocar a su inicio" significa llegar al principio?

Comment: Nunca había oído "tocar a su fin".  ¿Podrías incluir un ejemplo de su uso?

Comment: Hola, aparente001, aquí está el enlace a su definición ... https://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=tocar%20a%20su%20fin

Comment: Y ejemplos - https://www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/spanish-english/tocar-a-su-fin

Comment: Creo que una expresión análoga para un comienzo sería *dar inicio*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, *"tocar a su inicio"* no es una expresión que exista en castellano.

La expresión *"tocar a su fin"* no está en el Diccionario de la RAE y tampoco se deriva de ninguna de las acepciones de *[tocar](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Zw9dWu5)* en el DLE. No sé cuál es su origen, pero a mí me sugiere una relación con la idea de *tocar* como "acercarse y llegar hasta ponerse en contacto con alguna cosa". Esta idea implica que algo que está en movimiento **termina** su trayectoria cuando entra en contacto con otra cosa. Es decir, *tocar* implica el **fin** de un movimiento.

Estas connotaciones no permiten que se use algo como *"tocar a su inicio"*. Por lo demás, las expresiones idiomáticas no siempre tienen una lógica clara y son generalmente fijas o casi invariables, y no se puede innovar mucho sobre ellas.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones!